# Spring Cloud Config does not detect propertysource

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a problem that I don't quite understand why it happens I hope you can help me, first I give context

I am making an api with a microservices architecture all with Spring Boot and I created a service that acts as a configuration server with spring cloud server and when I did everything I realized that the server does not detect the configuration files, I will show you how they are:

The application.yml of the config service is:

```yaml
---
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/MarcossIC/Microservice-example.git
          search-path: config-data
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: config-service
...
```

The main class of the config service is:

```java
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I also show the configuration file that I want to add inside the config server, the file is for the "user-service" microservice, therefore I call it user-service.yml

```yaml
---
server:
  port: 8001
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
...
```

The bootstrap.yml of the user-service (it is the one that should refer to the configuration server within the microservice)

```yaml
---
spring:
  banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: user-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8081
...
```

In the dependencies in the user service add these dependencies for spring cloud

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In fact, these are the files that seem to me to be involved

Now the issue is that the server, although it starts up correctly and connects correctly to Git, when testing it, it does not detect the configuration files. I did a test with Postman and when trying to bring the configuration it tells me this

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
As can be seen in the image, I call an endpoint that spring cloud provides by default and the endopint path is made up of the name of the service that you want to configure, in this case "user-service" and the "default" property refers to that the "profile" is the default. Well, in the "propertySource" property, the configurations of the "user-service.yml" file should appear, but as you can see they are empty

When starting the user-service it is not configured correctly, it starts with the default port "8080" and not "8001"

Where could the problem be?

I want to make it clear that the project is uploaded to GitHub and if it connects correctly, in addition to this, no exceptions appear in the console, I must also add that the user-service project appears in the console if it connects to the config server but does not bring the settings.

I think the problem is in the "search-path" property but I'm not sure I leave a screenshot of the folder structure
[image]